# How to send data from PHP to Powershell

Tags: php, powershell

How can I send data from a website using PHP to Powershell on another host?

I’m trying to do so a button on my website triggers a Powershell script on my server computer. 
(Different host computers)

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Your question is at risk of being closed for the following standard reason: "Needs details or clarity: This question should include more details and clarify the problem." The linked help topic was meant to give you pointers toward improving your question, so as to prevent closure.

Comment: What more information do you need? Sorry if I’m retarded, first post here ish..